# Undefined mixin 'box-sizing'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2, box-sizing

I have a Rails 4.2.5 project that has been humming along.

Quite literally all of a sudden, I get this error:

```
Undefined mixin 'box-sizing'.
```

which points back to my stylesheet `include`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

I know it's not magic, so I must have done *something*. But I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

I'm not using the `compass-rails` gem, which I have seen in reference to this error.

I do not have `box-sizing` referenced directly anywhere in my code. I am using the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` but heretofore it hasn't caused any problems and has worked quite well.

Any light that anyone can shed on this, such as where to look for the reference, it very much appreciated.

***UPDATE***

I have since found that that the following gem I am using:

```
jquery-datatables-rails
```

has references to `box-sizing` in its CSS files. But I still don't know how to fix the error.

***UPDATE 2***

Removing that gem and all references to it does not fix the problem. There must be other gems using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling the assets in my development environment pointed exactly to the error:

rake assets:precompile

I had an outdated version of a `DataTables` plugin called `Editor`. I had generated this project from a template. As I'm not using Editor, I simply deleted it and this error went away.